# как сделать, если у тебя на странице много разных слайдеров

Tags: javascript, jquery, слайдер

В верстке иногда такие задачи будут в которых много разных слайдеров на одной странице. Когда подключаешь много jquery,js -кодов и выдает ошибку. Есть решение для такое случае или какие нибудь фишки?
Если у кого-то были такие случаи , можете поделиться ? 
Буду благодарен , Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 3):

использую "owl carousel" , там просто при создании новой карусели , делаешь новый обьект с нужным тебе именем(классом, ID) Пример:

```
$('.owl-carousel-clients').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:18,
    center: true,
    nav: false,
    items:1,
    dots:true

});
```

Делаешь таких сколько угодно , ругаться не будет

Comment: Спасибо за ответь. А со стилями как обращаться? если стили отлечаются друг от друга.

Comment: Ну класс это же обертка самой карусели , в зависимости от класса и даешь разные стили тем или иным элементам внутри

Comment: Спасибо большое